# Mongo Atlast URI Support In Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have been working on connecting clickhouse with mongo atlas and i found nothing in documentation, so i dig into the code and found that MongoDictionarySource.cpp in dbms folder there is no configuration for uri.
On more investigating i came to know that clickhouse is using poco c++ project for database connectivity. In clickhouse submoduled poco's Connection.cpp there is no constructor with uri support but when i go to https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/MongoDB/src/Connection.cpp , i found that Connection.cpp has constructor that support uri.
Is this updated poco version can be submoduled with clickhouse so that i can make dictionary in clickhouse with mongo atlas?
OR
Is there any release comming where it can be already provided?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is further discussed over here: https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/pull/5384